# Piping stdin to R

Tags: r, shell, pipe

I am having trouble piping stdin to an R script.

Here is my toy script `test.R`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
while(length(line <- readLines('stdin', n=1, warn=FALSE)) > 0) {
  write(line, stderr())
  # process line
}
```

I'd like to go through each line and do some processing. Here is my input file named `input`:

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
ffffff
```

If I do

```
cat input | test.R
```

I only get:

```
aaaaaa
```

Is there anything that I missed?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This does not happen if you explicitly open the stdin connection.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
f <- file("stdin")
open(f)
while(length(line <- readLines(f,n=1)) > 0) {
  write(line, stderr())
  # process line
}
```

Comment: Do we need to close file in the end?

Comment: If you want R to do the more typical "unix-y" thing and wait for input from stdin (so the code in the answer would behave similarly to running `cat` with no arguments) then you need to use `open(f, blocking=TRUE)`.

Comment: Also a tip for people (like me) who prefer `=` over `<-`: the `<-` *cannot* be replaced by `=` in `length(line <- readLines(f, n=1)`.

Comment: @dshepherd, the method in the answer (`file("stdin")`) is blocking by default. At least, the help page for `file` has a parameter `block = TRUE`

Comment: I guess this is a little off topic, but what if you have an actual file called `stdin`. Would you have to do `file("./stdin")`, or something like that, to access it?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: yes, that is what I would do.

Comment: For whatever reason this doesn’t work for me on a Linux system. I have to use `readLine("stdin")`. I’ve tried countless other variations, none worked; either no data was read or an error (invalid connection) was thrown.

Answer (score 15):

Jeff and I wrote [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) to do just this (and a few other things). Because of [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html), I never looked that closely at Rscript -- but this should *in principle* work just fine.

Here is one of our early examples, using output from `/bin/ls` (and a quick filter by `awk`) to summarize file size:

```
edd@max:~/svn/littler/examples$ ls -l /boot/ | \
                                    awk '!/^total/ {print $5}' | ./fsizes.r 
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
      24   130300   730700  3336000  4527000 14670000 

  The decimal point is 6 digit(s) to the right of the |

   0 | 0000000000000011111111122777777777
   2 | 777777777
   4 | 555577777
   6 | 
   8 | 
  10 | 
  12 | 5
  14 | 24466677

edd@max:~/svn/littler/examples$
```

Here the script `fsizes.r` is just three lines:

```
edd@max:~/svn/littler/examples$ cat fsizes.r 
#!/usr/bin/r -i

fsizes <- as.integer(readLines())
print(summary(fsizes))
stem(fsizes)
edd@max:~/svn/littler/examples$
```

Comment: readLines() reads all the lines into memory, which is what I am trying to avoid. I hope to read line by line, with n=1 in readLines()

Comment: So put an awk/sed/grep/... filter in the pipe, or dump to file and select.  R does indeed want all its input read.

Answer (score 6):

If the input are numbers you can use:

```r
x <- scan("stdin")
```

you can test it with:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3" | R -s -e 'x <- scan("stdin"); summary(x)'
Read 3 items
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    1.0     1.5     2.0     2.0     2.5     3.0
```

Adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42080340/253049) and tested in R 4.2.2.