# R - Reading STDIN line by line

Tags: r, streaming, line, readline

I want to stream a big data table into R LINE BY LINE, and if the current line has a specific condition (lets say the first columns is >15), add the line to a data frame in memory. I have written following code:

```
count<-1;
Mydata<-NULL;
fin <- FALSE;
while (!fin){
    if (count==1){
        Myrow=read.delim(pipe('cat /dev/stdin'), header=F,sep="\t",nrows=1);
        Mydata<-rbind(Mydata,Myrow);
        count<-count+1;
    }
    else {
        count<-count+1;
        Myrow=read.delim(pipe('cat /dev/stdin'), header=F,sep="\t",nrows=1);
        if (Myrow!=""){
        if (MyCONDITION){
            Mydata<-rbind(Mydata,Myrow);
        }
        }
        else
        {fin<-TRUE}
    }
}
print(Mydata);
```

But I get the error "data not available".
Please note that my data is big and I don't want to read it all in once and apply my condition (in this case it was easy).

Comment: You may be interested in the answers and comments on this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352887/strategies-for-reading-in-csv-files-in-pieces

Comment: see `?scan`, `?readLines`, `nrows` argument of `read.table`, and be aware that your solution will be **very** slow in R -- can you use Perl, or even awk, to pre-process?

Comment: How would my answer below fare in terms of speed? In essence I open a file and keep extracting lines from it without closing the file.

Comment: Please note that I want read data line by line. My problem is how to tell R that data is streaming in and lines should be received one by one. This is also very easy in Perl, but I was looking for a way to do it in R.

Answer (score 12):

I think it would be wiser to use an R function like `readLines`. `readLines` supports only reading a specified number of lines, e.g. 1. Combine that with opening a `file` connection first, and then calling `readLines` repeatedly gets you what you want. When calling `readLines` multiple times, the next `n` lines are read from the connection. In R code:

```
stop = FALSE
f = file("/tmp/test.txt", "r")
while(!stop) {
  next_line = readLines(f, n = 1)
  ## Insert some if statement logic here
  if(length(next_line) == 0) {
    stop = TRUE
    close(f)
  }
}
```

Additional comments:

- R has an internal way of treating stdin as file: `stdin()`. I suggest you use this instead of using `pipe('cat /dev/stdin')`. This probably makes it more robust, and definitely more cross-platform.
- You initialize `Mydata` at the beginning and keep growing it using `rbind`. If the number of lines that you `rbind` becomes larger, this will get really slow. This has to do with the fact that when the object grows, the OS needs to find a new memory location for it, which ends up taking **a lot** of time. Better is to pre-allocate `MyData`, or use apply style loops.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have a questions regarding it: As I mentioned, my data is very BIG and I don't want to read it into memory. In line 3 of your code, it seems that you are reading the whole data and then going through its lines. Am I right?

Comment: No, I open a connection and then read from it. `next_line` only contains only the current line. Using `file` only opens a connection, it does not read anything yet.

Comment: Ahan. thanks. what should I write instead of "/tmp/test.txt", the first argument of file() ?

Comment: I used the code you mentioned with file("stdin","r"); However, I cannot read more than 1 line when I stream into this in Linux using cat ToyData.txt | R --Vanilla --slave -f MyCode.R
Does anybody know why?

Comment: For standard in use `stdin()`, not `"stdin"`.

Comment: And I think you do not need the piping, just use `file("ToyData.txt", "r")`.

Comment: To read from stdin without losing lots of lines, you may need to explicitely open it, as noted in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370609/piping-stdin-to-r).

Comment: But what would be the advantage of using bash to pipe the file into R and catching it with stdin, in stead of just opening a file connection to the file?

Comment: just a small correction: In the code above, the file should be shifted to *before* loop.

Comment: Reading from stdin gives you a lot of free shell functionality (which I guess separates CS from Data Science folks).

Answer (score 2):

You can read `stdin` line by line using [`readLines`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/readLines) like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
input <- file("stdin", "r")
while (length(l <- readLines(input, n=1)) > 0) {
    l <- l[[1]]  # isolate the first line
    cat(l)       # prints the line
    cat("\n")
}
```

The above script, simply replicate all `stdin` lines into `stdout` like so:

```
$ cat in.txt
first
second
third

$ Rscript script.r <in.txt 
first
second
third
```

Above, in the [`readLines`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/readLines) function call, the `n=1` is needed to tell [`readLines`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/readLines) to read a maximum of one line, as we want to process everything line by line.  Note [`readLines`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/readLines) always returns a vector of length the number of lines read.  Since we are using `n=1` as argument, this means we either always get a vector of length one (`1`) when there are still lines to be read or zero (`0`) when we reach EOF (end-of-file) or some error.  This is why in the `while` condition we check if the length is greater than zero.  In this way, the loop will finish on EOF.

The original question also mentions checking a condition before saving the data in memory.  Here's an example with a condition (print lines with the length of 5):

```
input <- file("stdin", "r")
while (length(l <- readLines(input, n=1)) > 0) {
    l <- l[[1]]
    if (nchar(l)==5) {
        cat(l)
        cat("\n")
    }
}
```

Here's the output for the new script:

```
$ Rscript five.r <in.txt 
first
third
```