# excute R script from hive

Tags: r, hive

Does anybody knows who to read data from hive into R and then back to Hive?
I can do it easily with Python like this:

```
for line in sys.stdin:

  Some code ...

  sys.stdout.write(Output + '\n')
```

Is there a similar way in R?

Thanks
Tomer

Comment: You may be interested in the answers and comments on this q:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871307/r-reading-stdin-line-by-line

Comment: I am just curious why the title is "execute ...". What is being executed? I tried to change this to "Read data in Windows hive", but the change was rejected.

Comment: I'd guess it was rejected for the "Windows" part.  This has nothing to do with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

if you set up Rstudio on you hive server you can easily access it via R script. You would need the Rhive package.
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHive/

All you need to do after that is set your paths for hadoop and hive home in your R profile
and use

```
library(Rhive)
rhive.init()
rhcon<-rhive.connect(address,port=)
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ofir, I guess you can write your code in the some way in R.
Precisely:

```
conn <- file("stdin", open="r")
while (length(next.line <- readLines(conn, n=1, warn=FALSE)) > 0) { 
    # processing
    cat(output)
}
```