# Is there a way to use standard input/output stream to communicate C# and R?

Tags: c#, r, stdio

I want to build a C# program that is needed to communicate with R (`rscript.exe`) via standard input/output stream. But I can't find a way to write anything into rscript's input stream.

Here is the C# program that uses a Process whose streams are redirected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("rscript", "script.R") 
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            proc.Start();            

            var str = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("hello2");

            var str2 = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is `script.R`:

```
cat("hello\n")

input <- readline()

cat("input is:",input, "\n")
```

`str` is able to capture `"hello"` but `"hello2"` can't be written into R's stream so that `str2` always gets `"\r\ninput is:  \r\n"`.

Is there a way to write texts into R's input stream in this way?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9871307/602276

Comment: Why should one do this? With [R.NET](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) there exists a really great interface between C# and other .net dialects and R. You can easily interchange not only strings and scalars, but also vectors, matrices, lists, ... Have a look at this great piece of work and have fun :-)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoocks, I deliberately avoid using R.NET in this case for some reason, just want to know a minimal case to interact with an R session through stdio, I think I've solved the problem already. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9370949/2906900 works for this question.

Here's an minimal example in which C# and rscript.exe interact through stdio.

In the R script, `stdin` connection must be explicitly open.

R code:

```
f <- file("stdin")
open(f)
input <- readLines(f, n = 1L)
cat("input is:", input)
```

In this case, the input stream of rscript can be accessed.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("rscript")
            {
                Arguments = "script.R",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            proc.Start();
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("Hello");
            var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```