# Pipe R markdown through Knitr?

Tags: r, pipe, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I found out from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025123) that you can call [Knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) from a script like this:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('myfile.Rmd')
```

But is there a way to get it to use stdin and stdout instead of files?

I tried several variations on

```
Rscript -e 'library(knitr); knit2html(text=readLines(), output=stdout())'
```

but none have worked so far.

EDIT: I suppose worst case, I could write a wrapper script that writes stdin to a temp file, calls knitr on it, echoes the output file, and deletes them. But that's kind of ugly :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370609/piping-stdin-to-r perhaps.

Comment: and be sure to use the argument `quiet=TRUE` in `knit()` or `knit2html()` to suppress other possible messages that may pollute `stdout()`

Answer (score 1):

OK I tried it again today, and here's a working script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Hacky version of what I thought should be doable like so:
# Rscript -e 'library(knitr); knit2html(text=readLines(), output=stdout())'
# Turns out you need tempfiles for some reason?

input="/tmp/input.Rmd"
output="/tmp/output.html"
rcode="library(knitr); knit2html(input=\"$input\", output=\"$output\")"

cat /dev/stdin > "$input"
Rscript -e "$rcode" &> /dev/null
cat "$output"
```

You pipe R markdown in and HTML comes out. Ignores any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version:

```
#!/bin/Rscript
library(knitr)
input <- readLines('stdin')
invisible(knit(text=input, output=stdout(), quiet=TRUE))
```

Then (assuming script is `knit.R`, rmd file is `test.R` and md to html converted is `multimarkdown`:

```
knit.R < test.Rmd | multimarkdown > test.html
```