# Have an Rscript read or take input from stdin

Tags: r, bash, stdin

I see how to have an Rscript perform the operations I want when given a filename as an argument, e.g. if my Rscript is called `script` and contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript 
path <- commandArgs()[1]
writeLines(readLines(path))
```

Then I can run from the bash command line:

```
Rscript script filename.Rmd --args dev='svg'
```

and successfully get the contents of `filename.Rmd` echoed back out to me.  If instead of passing the above argument a filename like `filename.Rmd` I want to pass it text from `stdin`, I try modifying my script to read from stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript 
writeLines(file("stdin"))
```

but I do not know how to construct the commandline call for this case.  I tried piping in the contents:

```
cat filename.Rmd | Rscript script --args dev='svg'
```

and also tried redirect:

```
Rscript script --args dev='svg' < filename.Rmd
```

and either way I get the error:

```
Error in writeLines(file("stdin")) : invalid 'text' argument
```

(I've also tried `open(file("stdin"))`).  I'm not sure if I'm constructing the Rscript incorrectly, or the commandline argument incorrectly, or both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Piping stdin to R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370609/piping-stdin-to-r)

Comment: but your error might be using `writeLines` to read vs `readLines`

Comment: Thanks; using `readLines(file("stdin"))` in place of `open(file("stdin"))` solves my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to read text from the connection created by `file("stdin")` in order to pass anything useful to the `text` argument of `writeLines()`. This should work

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript 
writeLines(readLines(file("stdin")))
```