# call shell script from node.js

Tags: r, node.js, shell, exec

How can I generate a script in Node.js and pipe to the shell?

E.g. I can create this file, e.g. `hello.R`, make it executable `chmod +x hello.R` and run it from the command line, `./hello.R`:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
hello <- function( name ) { return (sprintf( "Hello, %s", name ); })
cat(hello("World"));
```

What I'd like to do is to do the equivalent from Node. Specifically generate a more complex R script in memory  (e.g. as a string using templating, etc.), execute it (using `exec` or `spawn`?), and read `stdout`.

But I can't quite figure out how to pipe a script to R.  I tried this (among other things):

```
var rscript = [       
    hello <- function( name ) { return (sprintf( "Hello, %s", name ); })
    cat(hello("World"));
].join('\n');

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec(rscript, { shell: '/usr/bin/R'}, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
   if (err) throw(err);
   console.log(stdout);
});
```

However, this fails as it seems neither `/usr/bin/R` nor `/usr/bin/Rscript` understand the `-c` switch:

Comment: Just for info, you can use [the rstats library](https://github.com/Planeshifter/node-Rstats), alternatively.

Answer (score 2):

Check the nodejs docs of [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). You should be able to `spawn` an `Rscript` or `R` command just as you would do on the terminal, and send your commands over `child.stdin`.

```
var c = require('child_process');
var r = c.spawn("R","");
r.stdin.write(rscript);
/* now you should be able to read the results from r.stdout a/o r.stderr */
```

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out the issue is R and Rscript don't read from stdin by default, and the workarounds (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370609/piping-stdin-to-r) don't play well with spawn.  Will noodle on that, for now am writing the code as a file to be read in by R.